# Merge Query taking more than 12 hours to execute any optimisation

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have the following query taking 12 hrs to execute, is it possible to optimise? The `DRV_START_DATE` of table `YYYYY` is of `NUMBER` datatype , so converting the input values to `to_number` will help.

```
MERGE INTO XXXX D USING(
   SELECT /*+parallel(a 10)*/ 
          a.BATCH_NUMBER,COUNT(*) AS CALL_COUNT 
     FROM YYYYY@LN_RAPROD a 
    WHERE a.DRV_START_DATE BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-7,'YYYYMMDD') 
                               AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') 
      AND a.TOTAL_TYPE =195 
    GROUP BY a.BATCH_NUMBER) 
ON (D.BATCH_NUMBER=S.BATCH_NUMBER)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET D.CALL_COUNT=S.CALL_COUNT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (D.BATCH_NUMBER,D.CALL_COUNT)
     VALUES (S.BATCH_NUMBER,S.CALL_COUNT)
```

Comment: Is your DRV_START_DATE a DATE or VARCHAR2 column?

Comment: @Ollie: The DRV_START_DATE of table YYYYY is of "NUMBER" datatype. I mentioned

Comment: So you did, I should learn to read the post fully! My apologies.

Comment: Please don't butcher questions by changing essential table, variable or object names. This rendered answers such as APC's somewhat broken.

Answer (score 3):

You have a distributed query, with the data coming from the remote site.  The default way Oracle works is to pull all the data from the remote site and filter it on the local site.

This might be a bad choice in your situation, depending on the relative data volumes.  If so, you could use the DRIVING_SITE hint, which would assess the join on the remote site and return the result to the local database.

I've never used DRIVING_SITE with a MERGE but I think something like this should work:

```
MERGE INTO XXXX D USING(
   SELECT /*+parallel(a 10)  DRIVING_SITE(YYYYY)*/ 
          a.BATCH_NUMBER,COUNT(*) AS CALL_COUNT 
     FROM YYYYY@LN_RAPROD a 
    WHERE a.DRV_START_DATE BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-7,'YYYYMMDD') 
                               AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') 
      AND a.TOTAL_TYPE =195 
    GROUP BY a.BATCH_NUMBER) 
ON (D.BATCH_NUMBER=S.BATCH_NUMBER)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET D.CALL_COUNT=S.CALL_COUNT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (D.BATCH_NUMBER,D.CALL_COUNT)
     VALUES (S.BATCH_NUMBER,S.CALL_COUNT)
```

---

Incidentally, are you sure that parallel hint is helping you?

Comment: PARALLEL hint  was given by  our dba team. sorry i am not good at depth in sql.

Comment: The question is, which database does it parallelise (dread word)?

Comment: APC: nice question.i will put this  to dba